# How to use dispersion correction with TPSSh in Gaussian 16?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, density-functional-theory, dispersion-correction

A colleague of mine suggested to use TPSSh as a functional. Since I am applying Grimme's D3 dispersion correction by default, I was surprised that it wasn't implemented in the standard density functionals, cf. [Gaussian Manual](http://gaussian.com/dft/?tabid=4) (Copy @ [The Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20181004165139/http://gaussian.com/dft/?tabid=4)).

Since I might not be the only one to come across that: **How can I use dispersion correction with TPSSh** (or other non-implemented functionals) **in Gaussian 16?**

In principle the following route section is in use:

```
#P TPSSh/def2TZVP           ! verbose, method/ basis set
EmpiricalDispersion(GD3BJ)  ! Switch on D3 with Becke-Johnson damping
opt(MaxCycle=100,VeryTight) ! Run optimisation
int(ultrafinegrid)          ! use finer grid for dfa
```

Related Error is if attempted:

```
 R6DS8: Unable to choose the S8 parameter, IExCor= 2523 IXCFnc= 35 ScaHFX=  0.100000 IDFTD=4
 Error termination via Lnk1e in [...] g16.b01_bin/l301.exe at Thu Oct  4 18:59:24 2018.
```

But it could also be the `S6`, `a1`, or `a2` parameter. If zero-damping is used, then it could also be `S6R`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is quite simple and already given in the manual:

> You can use this empirical dispersion method with other functionals via the IOps(3/174-178) (S6 should be 1.0).

Parameters and the standalone program can be found can be found on the DFTD3 homepage at [Mulliken Center for Theoretical Chemistry](https://www.chemie.uni-bonn.de/pctc/mulliken-center/software/dft-d3/). Here are links via The Internet archive to the tables for [zero-damping](https://web.archive.org/web/20181004171955/https://www.chemie.uni-bonn.de/pctc/mulliken-center/software/dft-d3/functionals) and [BJ-damping](https://web.archive.org/web/20181004171550/https://www.chemie.uni-bonn.de/pctc/mulliken-center/software/dft-d3/functionalsbj).

The Overlay3 manual can be found on [gaussian.com](http://gaussian.com/overlay3), or [The Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20180330060609/http://gaussian.com/overlay3):

> **IOp(3/174)**
>
> S6 scale factor in Grimme’s D2/D3/D3BJ dispersion.
>
> ```
> 0          Default (see subroutine R6DS6).
> -1         Set S6 to 0. 
> NNNNNNNN   A value of NNNNNNNN/1000000.
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **IOp(3/175)**
>
> S8 scale factor in Grimme’s D2/D3/D3BJ dispersion.
>
> ```
> 0          Default (see subroutine R6DS8).
> -1         Set S8 to 0. 
> NNNNNNNN   A value of NNNNNNNN/1000000.
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **IOp(3/176)**
>
> SR6 scale factor in Grimme’s D2/D3/D3BJ dispersion.
>
> ```
> 0          Default (see subroutine R6DSR6).
> -1         Set SR6 to 0. 
> NNNNNNNN   A value of NNNNNNNN/1000000.
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **IOp(3/177)**
>
> A1 parameter in Becke-Johnson damping for D3BJ and XDM.
>
> ```
> 0          Default (see subroutine R6DABJ/XDMABJ).
> -1         Set A1 to 0. 
> NNNNNNNN   A value of NNNNNN/1000000.
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **IOp(3/178)**
>
> A2 parameter in Becke-Johnson damping for D3BJ and XDM.
>
> ```
> 0          Default (see subroutine R6DABJ/XDMABJ).
> -1         Set A2 to 0. 
> NNNNNNNN   A value of NNNNNN/1000000 Ang.
> ```

For TPSSh the route section should therefore look similar to the following:

```
#P TPSSh/def2TZVP           ! verbose, method/ basis set
EmpiricalDispersion(GD3BJ)  ! Switch on D3 with Becke-Johnson damping
IOp(3/174=1000000)          ! Set s6 to 1.000
IOp(3/175=2238200)          ! Set s8 to 2.2382
IOp(3/177=452900)           ! Set a1 to 0.4529
IOp(3/178=4655000)          ! Set a2 to 4.6550
opt(MaxCycle=100,VeryTight) ! Run optimisation
int(ultrafinegrid)          ! use finer grid for dfa
```